# Recovery services vault Vs VM Clone - Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have been trying to find a way to clone ARM VM without deallocating it , so that the VMs can be replicated for different user groups on a need basis. Looks like Azure Recovery Services Vault can be used to achieve my goal though the intended purpose of the service is not really to clone a new VM. So my question is on the design side of these two services.

1. Could anyone shed light as to why ARM VM clone procedure mandates de-allocation of the cloned ? Which use cases are actually solved by that service ?
2. If I use Recovery Service Vault to create a new VM from an existing one , is there any side effect to it (technical/financial) ?
3. The AWS way of getting a copy of VM - Get a snapshot , create one from it - sounded simpler and user friendly to me. The Azure way of providing two different services for similar goals - Any insight to that kind of design decision making ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. probably by design. it cant access page blob that is leased.
2. well, you install vm agent, you pay for ASR, you pay for protected VM.
3. You can create snapshots from managed disks no problem.

Comment: //it cant access page blob that is leased.//. Okay.Would you know the exact use case(s) that is/are served by a cloning procedure ?

Comment: not sure I understand the question, can you rephrase?

Comment: Is the clone procedure strictly used to create VM images ? Because once a VM is cloned , it cant be run - generalized and deallocated. It then becomes a template.So the question is , is that the sole purpose of clone procedure ?

Comment: Marking this as accepted because  this was sufficient to further my understanding about the aspects I was asking about.